# Optimize this Remove() method in C

Tags: c, arrays, string

This is a method use to remove the 'key' from char array.

**version 1:**

```
/* remove character key by two loop */
char *Remove(char *str, const char key)
{
    int len = strlen(str);
    for (int i = 0; i < len; i++)
        if (str[i] == key)
        {
            for (int j = i--; j <= len; j++)
                str[j] = str[j + 1];
        }
    return str;
}
```

**version 2:**

```
/* remove character key by one loop */
char *Remove(char *str, const char key)
{
    char *p1, *p2;

    p1 = p2 = str;
    while (*p2)
    {
        if (*p1 == *p2 && *p1 != key)
                p1++;
        else if (*p2 != key)
            *p1++ = *p2;
        p2++;
    }
    *p1 = *p2;  // assign '\0' to *p1
    return str;
}
```

I want to optimize the version 2, any body has any idea?

Comment: Yes, I have an idea.  Are you sure version 2 is an improvement over version 1?

Comment: so you need to use only one loop for version 2?

Comment: @CareyGregoryIsn't it? version 2 has only one loop.

Comment: @tristanYes, I want to use one loop and use less code. :) but don't know how to do.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I respectfully suggest that this loop is simpler.  Compared with the functions in the question, it is O(N) time, whereas the code for the first function in the question is O(N*N) if the `key` character appears.  The second is O(N), but the loop body is quite complex.

```
char *Remove(char *str, char key)
{
    char *dst = str;
    for (char *src = str; *src != '\0'; src++)
    {
        if (*src != key)
            *dst++ = *src;
    }
    *dst = '\0';
    return dst;  // Or src, but knowing the end is more useful!
}
```

Clearly, if you don't have a C99 compiler, you could place the declaration of `src` outside the loop.

---

I used the following code to satisfy myself that the code in [randomusername](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2898458/randomusername)'s [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20852625/15168) is now correct (and produces the same answer as my code):

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

static char *Remove2(char *s, char key)
{
    char *p1, *p2;
    p1 = p2 = s;
    do
    {
        while (*p2 == key)
            p2++;
        *p1++ = *p2++;
    }
    while (p2[-1]);
    return p2 - 1;
}

static char *Remove1(char *str, char key)
{
    char *dst = str;
    for (char *src = str; *src != '\0'; src++)
    {
        if (*src != key)
            *dst++ = *src;
    }
    *dst = '\0';
    return dst;  // Or src, but knowing the end is more useful!
}

int main(void)
{
    char data1[32] = "AB=CD==EF===GHI\0AAAAA";
    char data2[32] = "AB=CD==EF===GHI===\0AAAAA";
    char data[32];
    char *end;

    memmove(data, data1, sizeof(data));
    end = Remove1(data, '=');
    printf("[%s] => [%s] (%d)\n", data1, data, (int)(end - data));

    memmove(data, data1, sizeof(data));
    Remove2(data, '=');
    printf("[%s] => [%s] (%d)\n", data1, data, (int)(end - data));

    memmove(data, data2, sizeof(data));
    Remove1(data, '=');
    printf("[%s] => [%s] (%d)\n", data2, data, (int)(end - data));

    memmove(data, data2, sizeof(data));
    Remove2(data, '=');
    printf("[%s] => [%s] (%d)\n", data2, data, (int)(end - data));

    return 0;
}
```

Output:

```
[AB=CD==EF===GHI] => [ABCDEFGHI] (9)
[AB=CD==EF===GHI] => [ABCDEFGHI] (9)
[AB=CD==EF===GHI===] => [ABCDEFGHI] (9)
[AB=CD==EF===GHI===] => [ABCDEFGHI] (9)
```

Comment: I already know where the start of the string is; I don't need the function to tell me that.  I don't know where the end of the string is; it is useful to know that.  I have a grudge against functions such as `strcpy()` that don't tell you where the end of the string is.  Of course, one counter-argument is 'you should know how long the source and destination are before you start copying', and there's a fair amount of truth in that, too.  However, with these `Remove` functions, you can't tell how long the result will be, but the function knows.  (`fgets()` is a nuisance too!)

Comment: got it, thank you. By the way, where can I read the source code of string in c/c++, like remove() and other functions? :)

Comment: A lot of the source for that will be in the GCC (GNU Compiler Collection) source code; it must be there for C++ support.  You might also look at source for the GNU C Library, glibc.  Then there are a number of open source versions of the STL (Standard Template Library); you can look there, too.  Boost would be another place to look.  A Google search using 'stl template library source' shows SGI and SXXTL as two sources of STL.

Answer (score 3):

Why not just use,

```
p1 = p2 = s;
do
  {
    while (*p2 == key) p2++;
    *p1++ = *p2++;
  }
while (p2[-1]);
```

I know there are many capitalization errors; I am currently at the mercy of my Blackberry's auto-correct.

Comment: What happens if the last character in the string matches the key? I'm not convinced that everyone will be happy with the behaviour.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler then the last character will be overwritten with the terminating null byte.  Although it could cause a segmentation fault, I'll fix it.

Comment: And `p2` will point to the character after the null byte, and the next iteration of the loop will test that, and it might not be a null byte, so you might go trampling a long way through memory.

Comment: you need to add `*p1 = *p2;` at the end of loop

Comment: @nav_jan I shouldn't need to do that, can you give me an example where I need that?

Comment: When the last character of the string is not the key?

Comment: Note that C keywords are all lower case, and C is a case-sensitive language so `P1` and `p1` are separate variables. I quietly fixed your previous peccadilloes, but you've reintroduced them.  (Oh, ugh; nowadays, some keywords are not all lower-case, but those that are not start with an underscore: `_Bool`, etc.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler I'm doing this off of my blackberry, and it's really hard to fix all the capitalization "auto-corrects" it forces on me.

Comment: Then, with due respect, don't use a Blackberry, or iPhone, or Android, for this job.  I'll fix it for you, but beware.  Oh; you managed to get there first.  I did wonder whether there was something getting in your way.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler I know, I should definitely be using a real computer for this... Thank you by the way for correcting my earlier capitalization struggles.

Comment: It's ironic that adding the explanation that you're using a b[sic]lackberry reintroduced the keyword capitalization errors. As Jonathan said, just don't do it.